# How to extract values from excel sheet where few rows are formatted as number but few are text in Python

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I have an excel sheet where some of the rows are formatted as `number` but some of the rows are formatted as `text`. I have python script which reads each row and convert it into json and process it. Excel sheet looks like below:

[image]

In the above image, we can see that values in row 98, 99, 100, 101, 102 column 1 are formatted as text but values in row 103, 104 column 1 are formatted as number. I have below python code to access it:

```
import xlrd
wb = xlrd.open_workbook("file.xlsx")

sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(4)

for i in range(4, 185): #from 5th row to 186th row
    data = dict()
    print(str(sheet.cell_value(i, 0)))
    data['ProductNumber'] = str(sheet.cell_value(i, 0))
```

I have to save the values in `str` and thus I have used `str`. But I get below results for above rows 98 to 104

```
ROW     Value Extracted
98          907
99          088
100         019
101         274
102         905
103         290.0
104         971.0
```

Above results looks fine for row 98 to 102 but for 103, 104 row its wrong. It should be only `290 & 971`. To do this I put an `int` before `str` like below:

```
str(int(sheet.cell_value(i, 0)))
```

Now using this above results looks like below:

```
ROW     Value Extracted
98          907
99          88
100         19
101         274
102         905
103         290
104         971
```

This again is wrong because the values for row 99 and 100 should be `088` & `019` and not `88` & `19`. How can I resolve this issue. Is there any check I can use which can help me decide this . I am using [xlrd](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) python module.

Comment: IMO the correct answer depends on your requirement. To me it looks like the implicit requirement is, that the ProductNumber in your result after processing is not a number in the sense of an integer but a string containing only numerical values that is n=3 characters long. So maybe `str(sheet.cell_value(i, 0)).zfill(3)` does the trick? https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_zfill.asp

Comment: @konstantin `str(sheet.cell_value(i, 0)).zfill(3)` with `cell_value(i, 0)` as `290.0` will yield `290.0`, he should use `str(int(sheet.cell_value(i,0))).zfill(3)` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your example set of data, this would work:

```py
str(int(sheet.cell_value(i,0))).zfill(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas is another option, please use the below code to convert the same. The variable strJson holds the complete Json string here, if you add decimal points to your data it will automatically take it and if there is no decimal values the same will be added to json.

```
import pandas
strDataDump=pandas.read_excel('C:\Temp\Python Projects\data.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
strJson = strDataDump.to_json()
print('JSON Result:\n', strJson)
```